# Why postgres choose wrong execution plan

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

I have a simple query

```
select count(*)
from taxi_order.ta_orders o
  inner join public.t_bases b on b.id = o.id_base
where o.c_phone2 = '012356789'
  and b.id_organization = 1
  and o.c_date_end < '2017-12-01'::date
group by date_trunc('month', o.c_date_end);
```

Most of time this query runs fast in less then 100 ms but sometimes it starts run very slow up to 4 seconds for some c_phone2, id_organization combinations.

Execution plan for fast case:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=7005.05..7005.62 rows=163 width=8)
  Group Key: date_trunc('month'::text, o.c_date_end)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=94.30..7004.23 rows=163 width=8)
        Hash Cond: (o.id_base = b.id)
        ->  Index Scan using ix_ta_orders_c_phone2 on ta_orders o  (cost=0.57..6899.41 rows=2806 width=12)
              Index Cond: ((c_phone2)::text = $3)
              Filter: (c_date_end < $4)
        ->  Hash  (cost=93.26..93.26 rows=133 width=4)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bases b  (cost=4.71..93.26 rows=133 width=4)
                    Recheck Cond: (id_organization = $2)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_bases_id_organization  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=133 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (id_organization = $2)
```

Execution plan for slow case:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=6604.97..6604.98 rows=1 width=8)
  Group Key: date_trunc('month'::text, o.c_date_end)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2195.33..6604.97 rows=1 width=8)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bases b  (cost=2.29..7.78 rows=3 width=4)
              Recheck Cond: (id_organization = $2)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_bases_id_organization  (cost=0.00..2.29 rows=3 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (id_organization = $2)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ta_orders o  (cost=2193.04..2199.06 rows=3 width=12)
              Recheck Cond: (((c_phone2)::text = $3) AND (id_base = b.id) AND (c_date_end < $4))
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2193.04..2193.04 rows=3 width=0)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_ta_orders_c_phone2  (cost=0.00..58.84 rows=3423 width=0)
                          Index Cond: ((c_phone2)::text = $3)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_ta_orders_id_base_date_end  (cost=0.00..2133.66 rows=83472 width=0)
                          Index Cond: ((id_base = b.id) AND (c_date_end < $4))
```

Why query planer chooses so slow ineffective plan sometimes?

EDIT

Schema for tables:

```
craete table taxi_order.ta_orders (
  id bigserial not null,
  id_base integer not null,
  c_phone2 character varying(30),
  c_date_end timestamp with time zone,
...
  CONSTRAINT pk_ta_orders PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ta_orders_t_bases REFERENCES public.t_bases (id)
);

craete table public.t_bases (
  id serial not null,
  id_organization integer not null,
...
  CONSTRAINT pk_t_bases PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

ta_orders ~ 100M rows, t_bases ~ 2K rows.

EDIT2

Explain analyze for slow case:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=6355.29..6355.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4075.847..4075.847 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: date_trunc('month'::text, o.c_date_end)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2112.10..6355.28 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=114.871..4075.803 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bases b  (cost=2.29..7.78 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.061..0.375 rows=133 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (id_organization = $2)
              Heap Blocks: exact=45
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_bases_id_organization  (cost=0.00..2.29 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=133 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (id_organization = $2)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ta_orders o  (cost=2109.81..2115.83 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=30.638..30.638 rows=0 loops=133)
              Recheck Cond: (((c_phone2)::text = $3) AND (id_base = b.id) AND (c_date_end < $4))
              Heap Blocks: exact=2
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2109.81..2109.81 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=30.635..30.635 rows=0 loops=133)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_ta_orders_c_phone2  (cost=0.00..58.85 rows=3427 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=6 loops=133)
                          Index Cond: ((c_phone2)::text = $3)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_ta_orders_id_base_date_end  (cost=0.00..2050.42 rows=80216 width=0) (actual time=30.108..30.108 rows=94206 loops=133)
                          Index Cond: ((id_base = b.id) AND (c_date_end < $4))
```

Explain analyze for fast case:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=7005.05..7005.62 rows=163 width=8) (actual time=0.927..0.928 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: date_trunc('month'::text, o.c_date_end)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=94.30..7004.23 rows=163 width=8) (actual time=0.903..0.913 rows=2 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (o.id_base = b.id)
        ->  Index Scan using ix_ta_orders_c_phone2 on ta_orders o  (cost=0.57..6899.41 rows=2806 width=12) (actual time=0.591..0.604 rows=4 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((c_phone2)::text = $3)
              Filter: (c_date_end < $4)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2
        ->  Hash  (cost=93.26..93.26 rows=133 width=4) (actual time=0.237..0.237 rows=133 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on t_bases b  (cost=4.71..93.26 rows=133 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.196 rows=133 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (id_organization = $2)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=45
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_bases_id_organization  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=133 width=0) (actual time=0.044..0.044 rows=133 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id_organization = $2)
```

I know I can create separate index for every query to speed it up. But I want to know what is the reason for choosing wrong plan? What is wrong with my statistic?

Comment: I think we need more information. What is the schema of these two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to give us `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a definitive answer.

The difference between the plans is that the second plan chooses a nested loop join because it estimates that only very few rows will be selected from `t_bases`. Since you complain that the query is slow, that estimate is probably wrong, resulting in too many loops over the inner table.

Try to improve your table statistics by running `ANALYZE`, perhaps after increasing `default_statistics_target`.

A multi-column index on `ta_orders(c_phone2, id_base, c_date_end)` would improve the execution time for the nested loop plan.

Comment: I have added explain analyze results in my question. There are significant row estimation error in this line: `Bitmap Index Scan on ix_t_bases_id_organization  (cost=0.00..2.29 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=133 loops=1)`. Can it be a reason of choosing wrong plan?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly the reason. Try running `ANALYZE`. If you need to increase `default_statistics_target` for `ANALYZE` to get good enough statistics, you can make the setting permanent with `ALTER TABLE t_bases ALTER id_organization SET STATISTICS 1000;` (or higher).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I can suggest a possible improvement to your query: remove the inner join. You're not selecting anything from that table, so why bother querying it? You should be able to add `where o.id_base = ?` to your query.

If you want this query to run quickly every time you should add the following index to `ta_orders`: `(id_base, c_phone2, c_date_end)`. It's important that the column with the `>` or `<` where clause is at the end (otherwise Postgres will not be able to make use of it).

Comment: Yes I can add `where o.id_base in (select id from public.t_bases where id_organization = ?)` but it gives exact the same plan. There are indexes on c_phone2, c_date_end, id_base and (id_base, c_date_end). Planner decided to use ix_ta_orders_id_base_date_end in slow plan. IMHO this is wrong decision because this index is much less selective then ix_ta_orders_c_phone2 according to rows estimation.